# how do i write "?%" for sql in a way which would be accepted?

Tags: mysql

```
    Search(request,respond){
        var name =request.params.name;
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM search.items WHERE name LIKE '?%'";
        db.query(sql,name,function(error,result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                respond.json(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm not really sure about the problem but i think '?%' is being treated as a string how do i write '?%' without ? being treated as a string but a value to be replaced by the user input which is name?

Comment: Which language/framework is it? JS and ...?

Comment: Does `... LIKE concat(?, '%')` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM search.items WHERE name LIKE CONCAT("%",your_variable,"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your wildcard against your parameter, not inside your SQL string.

```
Search(request,respond){
    var name =request.params.name;
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM search.items WHERE name LIKE ?";
    db.query(sql,'%'+name+'%',function(error,result){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        else{
            respond.json(result);
        }
    });
}
```